# Q: Google Earth Engine: Calculating deforestation for individual areas (Hansen/Global Forest Change dataset)

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am looking to study deforestation around specific coordinates in Sub-Saharan Africa using the Global Forest Change dataset. For this purpose, I constructed a KML file using free online tool (https://www.freemaptools.com/radius-around-point.htm). In the KML file I have drawn a single circle around each coordinate. In my study, I am looking to assess deforestation within these circled areas over the years.

My problem is that Google Earth Engine treats the circles in the KML file as a single layer, rather than individual areas. Hence I can only calculate deforestation statistics for the combined area of the circles rather than for them individually.

Question: How / with what program should I construct the KML file in order to be able to calculate deforestation statistics for the circles individually?

Link to my code is here: 
https://code.earthengine.google.com/0b5248d458bee56c689994b1128f1e02

Answer (score 2):

Your KML works just fine, the issue is with how you imported it into GEE.

When you import the FusionTable without the appended `.geometry()` each circle will be a Feature inside a FeatureCollection, i.e. a single polygon instead of a multipolygon.

```js
var testi = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1tL57tZn65mmsf-sNST-Ag1DQzqCehPs7eGeiUJry');
```

You can then use `reduceRegions` to sum the pixels within each circle:

```js
// Sum the values of loss pixels in testi.
var stats = areaImage.reduceRegions({
  collection: testi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  scale: 30
});
print('sum of pixels representing loss in each circle:', stats)
```

Complete script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/ff41f0b95243dded25b709ffad9a746e